# Equivalence between the two form of Baire's theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X,d)$ a complete metric space.

I form: let $\forall n \quad V_n \subset X$ open and dense sets in $X$ then $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} V_n$ is dense in $X$

II form : let $\forall n \quad F_n \subset X$ closed and nowhere dense then $(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}F_n)^°=\emptyset$

Can I use the theorem a set is open and dense if and only if its complementar is closed and nowhere dense?

$X=\overline{\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} V_n}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}V_n^c$ and $V_n^c $ are closed and nowhere dense (for the theorem which I want use).

So $(V_n^c)^°=\emptyset$ and then $(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}V_n^c)^°=\emptyset $?This prove the equivalence of the two forms?

Comment: If you (officially) know this theorem, or give a proof of it, then you can use it. And using it is a good idea.

Comment: It's right my proof up?